# React: Detect Selected option on Custom switch button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have created a textual switch button using HTML and CSS.
I am using that in a React app and I want to detect the selected option whenever it changes. for e.g. if `OR` is selected, it should be stored in `selectedOption` state and if `AND` is selected, that should be stored.

I have made a code sandbox with the demo (https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-snyder-lo530)

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Having so much of the logic for you component in the css probably isn't the best way forward, but here is an option to do what you are asking: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-flower-q7x6y?file=/src/App.tsx). It just declares an `options` object and sets the state based on the `e.target.checked` value of your custom checkbox.

Comment: @pilchard thank you so much. Can you please guide me a little in the direction you mentioned? Thanks again

Comment: short answer `onChange(e => setSelectedOption(e.target.checked ? "AND" : "OR"))`. If `input[type=checbox]` is doing the job then leave it at it (and you'll nicely have keyboard support and basic accessibility). Do not forget to set the value (unless you want to keep it as uncontrolled input!) so you'll also need: `<input value={selectedOption === "AND"} ...other stuff... />`

Answer (score 0):

set the state on click, by adding this:

```
onClick={(e) =>{ 
     selectedOption==="OR" ? setSelectedOption("AND") : setSelectedOption("OR"),
    console.log(selectedOption);
    }}
```

Comment: you can remove console.log

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope, if you need to read the old value then you should use `setSelectedOption(current => current === "AND" ? "OR" : "AND")` and in general I'd avoid to use ternary operator when invoking functions with side effects, WHEN needed a plain `if` is way more clear for the reader.
Additionally: this handles only mouse interactions: any half-accessible code should at least support keyboard as well (plus checking any `disabled` or `readonly` attribute, if possible...)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @pilchard in comment, `e.target.checked` can be used to detect `true/false` and then based on that `selectedOption` can be set.

```
onClick={e => {
    const currentVal = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked;
    setSelectedOption(currentVal ? 'AND' : 'OR');
}}
```